# Select second largest area in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I use `bwareaopen` to remove small objects. Is there a function to remove the *big objects*? I'm trying to adapt bwareaopen however haven't been successful so far. Thanks

For ref: Here's a link to the help of [bwareaopen](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwareaopen.html).

Comment: please provide an example for an input image, with further explanation regarding to the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way if you don't want to use `bwareaopen` is to use [`regionprops`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), specifically with the `Area` and `PixelIdxList` attributes, filter out the elements that don't conform to the area range you want, then use the remaining elements and create a new mask.  `Area` captures the total area of each shape while `PixelIdxList` captures the column major linear indices of the locations inside the image that belong to each shape.  You would use the `Area` attribute to perform your filtering while you would use the `PixelIdxList` attribute to create a new output image and set these locations to `true` that are within the desired area range:

```
% Specify lower and upper bounds
LB = 30;
UB = 50;

% Run regionprops
s = regionprops(I, 'Area', 'PixelIdxList');

% Get all of the areas for each shape
areas = [s.Area];

% Remove elements from output of regionprops
% that are not within the range
s = s(areas >= LB & areas <= UB);

% Get the column-major locations of the shapes
% that have passed the check
idx = {s.PixelIdxList};
idx = cat(1, idx{:});

% Create an output image with the passed shapes
Iout = false(size(I));
Iout(idx) = true;
```

Comment: My pleasure!... Though using XOR with `bwareaopen` is very smart.

Comment: @user2305193 BTW, you CAN implement the opposite of `bwareaopen`.  All you would need to do is use the output of `bwareaopen` to index into your image and set the locations of those that are remaining to false.  This results in keeping the small objects while the large objects are removed.... so something like `Iout = bwareaopen(I, 50); I(Iout) = false;`

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy way to tackle this problem described [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/46398-removing-objects-which-have-area-greater-and-lesser-than-some-threshold-areas-and-extracting-only-th):
"To keep only objects between, say, 30 pixels and 50 pixels in area, you can use the BWAREAOPEN command, like this:"

```
LB = 30;
UB = 50;
Iout = xor(bwareaopen(I,LB),  bwareaopen(I,UB));
```